# Find date from range

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have table:

```
City | Start_date
---------------------------
London | 2015-01-01
Paris | 2015-02-15
Moscov | 2015-05-13
Sydney | 2015-07-13
Berlin | 2015-09-03
New York | 2015-09-28
Los Angeles | 2015-10-15
San Francisco | 2015-10-29
```

I create query:

```
Select City, Start_date 
from Table 
where Start_date between '2015-06-01' and '2015-09-30'
```

I have output:

```
City | Start_date
---------------------
Sydney | 2015-07-13
Berlin | 2015-09-03
New York | 2015-09-28
```

but I want output:

```
City | Start_date
---------------------
Moscov | 2015-05-13
Sydney | 2015-07-13
Berlin | 2015-09-03
New York | 2015-09-28
```

In my query I don't have Moscow. I like to create query to take all city from range date where user is present between date.

Comment: `'2015-06-01'` is after `2015-05-13`.  Why do you think your output is wrong?  Can't you just change `'2015-06-01'` to `'2015-05-12'`, or is a different result desired?

Comment: Since you don't give a End_Date column SQL engine ill not guess if the travler is still at Moscow. The problem here is to make the query to make the assumption the End_Date is the next Start_Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create an end date column by joining the table to itself and selecting the min of dates after the start date and subtracting 1 day.

```
SELECT Table1.StartDate, MIN(Table2.StartDate) - 1 AS EndDate
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.StartDate < Table2.StartDate
GROUP BY Table1.StartDate
HAVING Table1.StartDate <= [Time Period End Date]
    AND (MIN(Table2.StartDate) - 1) >= [Time Period Start Date]
```

Comment: This is it. I add:
union
Select top 1 StartDate, '2099-12-31' from Table1

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select a.City, a.Start_date 
from Table a 
   left join table b
      on b.Start_Date = 
            (Select Min(Start_Date)
             from table
             where Start_Date > a.Start_Date) 
where a.Start_date <= '2015-09-30' 
    and b.start_Date >=  '2015-06-01'
```

Comment: Almost, when I give a.Start_date <= '2016-01-01' I don't have San Francisco.